# Is there anything behind the “$m + N$” notation for elements in the factor structure $M/N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Or to be more precise,

> Is there anything behind the “$m + N$” notation for elements in the factor structure $M/N$ other than a hint at the set-theoretical realization?,

for example, if $M$ and $N$ are abelian groups.

---

*Why I’m asking*: I try *not* to think of composed structures in terms of their set-theoretic realization, but maybe there are other, more structural reasons to maintain this notation instead of any other (like $[m]_N$ for instance).

Also, do you know any other alternative notations for elements in the factor structure?

Comment: Often we use the notation $gN$ for elements in $M/N$. It's just a useful notation that keeps things as clear as possible. If you think about it, what is $M/N$? It's just the set of cosets of $N$ in $M$ which are elements of the form $gn$ where $g\in M$ and $n\in N$. Thus the notation $gN$ is pretty reasonable since it indicates that we're multiplying $N$ by $g$ on the left. In the case of an abelian group, some authors like to denote the group operation by $+$ so that $gN$ can really be thought of as $g+N$ in this case.

Comment: You mean, you are not interested in the fact that $m + N = \{ m + n : n \in N\}$?

Comment: And in set theoretic notation, we often use the notation $x+A$ to be $\{x+a:a\in A\}$. Other algebraic operations follow in much the same way. So the notation $gN$ is consistent with established set theoretic notation anyway.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti No, not particularly. It only tells me that the partition of $M$ into $N$-cosets in $M$ is a realization of the factor structure $M/N$. Okay, this can be very useful from time to time – but most of the time, it’s not what I need, so why should I accent it through my notation?

Comment: OK. The best notation is the one that is more practical to you, the one that makes it easier for you to think and to calculate. The only constraint is that when you write things up, you should write them following reasonable notational conventions, lest you impose a burden on the interested reader, that already elusive creature.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Okay, thank you. So do you know whether there’s anything behind this notation or do you know of any alternative notations?

Comment: alternatives include $[m]$, $\bar{m}$, $p(m)$ ($p$ is the projection onto the quotient).